# In digikam, when finding duplicates, how to decide which is the "reference image"? I.e. how to decide which duplicates to eliminate?

Tags: digital, digikam

I am using digiKam, and I have loaded all my photos.
I have several duplicates, sitting in different disks/folders.

I discovered the "find duplicates" function, and the "remove duplicates" function, but I don't understand how this last works: which is the criterion used to identify the reference image? (i.e. the copy that is kept, while the others are sent to the wastebin)
Is there a way to change this criterion?

I read the manual, and only found a short description of the function, without the details I am asking.
Also a google search did not give any more details.

I have digiKam version 7.4.0, in Linux Mint 20.2

Comment: Did you try searching the web and/or manual? If so, could you include in your question what things you've searched for, found and were not helpful? That narrows down the options others might suggest.

Comment: I shortened the question, and made it clearer (I hope).

Comment: Clarity is not the issue with this question. It's perfectly clear what you want to know. However, it is not clear what [research you've done yourself](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Did you look in the manual? Did you look online? What did you find? If what you found was not helpful, why not?

Comment: I see your point. I added some description about my research and attempts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for ["digikam find duplicates reference"](https://www.google.com/search?q=digikam+find+duplicates+reference) on the web I found [this Reddit post (titled "Digikam Reference Photos - How are they determined?")](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/rbvyh6/digikam_reference_photos_how_are_they_determined/) as the third sub-result of the first hit.

A commenter refers to a [related feature request](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444578#c1) about the selection of the original in duplicate search. This feature request is closed with [this commit](https://invent.kde.org/graphics/digikam/-/commit/69248f3a789a85251bad769fd5f62148ed5cd0c6) in the 7.4.0 version (bolding mine):

> use the **oldest image date or larger pixel/file size as the reference image**
> So far, the reference image was actually more of a "coincidence", depending on the image ID in the database. That makes little sense, because we are looking for the original image if possible.

From the [code](https://invent.kde.org/graphics/digikam/-/commit/69248f3a789a85251bad769fd5f62148ed5cd0c6) it doesn't seem that this behaviour is configurable, but I might be mistaken.